# File attributes on a NAS Drive not reporting user information

Tags: windows-server-2012, filesystems, network-attached-storage

We have a Synology NAS drive attached to a server 2012 network, but the file attributes do not report who last modified any of the files? Does the NAS need to be reconfigured or is it a configuration in Server 2012?

The NAS is NOT joined to the domain from its own OS, could this be the problem?

Comment: Do you expect them to? As far as I'm aware, neither NFS nor CIFS track who modified the files. That's the realm of auditing.

Comment: Just had a request to show in the file details who last modified the file on the NAS, but if NFS do not track it then I will have to find another solution

Comment: OK. Yes, you probably can't do that, unless you've turned on auditing somewhere. Auditing is an annoying overhead - it's a log of lots of system operations, so means it hurts performance, disk space etc. so often isn't enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS doesn't save file modification times or attributes like that. If you need it, use a LUN and iSCSI to a server that can host the files and use a filesystem that does this (NTFS, etc).